# Display the nearest date from the list if the passed date is not in the list

Tags: c#

I have a list of Datetime values.
I'm going to pass a datetime value as a parameter.
If the passed datetime value exists it will display the value if not it has to display the nearest value from the list

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `DateList.Min(d => dateReference - d);`

Comment: @Nalka That will get you the smallest difference.

Comment: he asked for the nearest didn't he?

Comment: Yes, OP asked for the _nearest item_, not the _smallest difference_. You're finding the smallest result of `dateReference - d`.

Comment: How can you determine the nearest if the parameter is gonna be null? The nearest to current date?

Comment: ah alright i think i get what you mean @John then what about `DateList.Min(d => (dateReference - d) + (d - dateReference));`?

Comment: DateList.OrderBy(d=> Math.Abs(dateReference - d)).First()

Comment: @nalka Personally I'd go for `DateList.OfType<DateTime?>().OrderBy(d => Math.Abs((dateReference - d.Value).Ticks)).FirstOrDefault()` - and then the result will be `null` or the closest date.

Comment: @John it will return always the first date in the list, -N will always be < 0

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I'd use something like this:

```
var closest = dateList
    .OfType<DateTime?>() // Convert values to `DateTime?` instead of `DateTime` so that we can return a `null` value.
    .OrderBy(d => Math.Abs((dateReference - d.Value).Ticks)) // sort from the smallest difference to biggest difference
    .FirstOrDefault(); // take the first item or null
```

Alternatively if you're sure your list will always have items (or you check beforehand), you can return a regular `DateTime` and skip the `DateTime?` conversion step:

```
var closest = dateList
    .OrderBy(d => Math.Abs((dateReference - d).Ticks)) // sort from the smallest difference to biggest difference
    .First(); // take the first item
```

Breakdown:

- `(dateReference - d)` obtains a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netframework-4.7.2), which has a `Ticks` property.
- `Math.Abs(ticks)` ensures that the value is always positive (since we don't care if the date is earlier or later)
- `.OrderBy()` orders smallest to largest
- `.First()` takes the first item.

Answer (score 1):

If the array of dates is sorted you should be able to find the nearest date using a binary search. 
O(log n) time

```
var index = Array.BinarySearch(sorted, date);
DateTime found;

if(index >= 0)
   found = sorted[index]; //Date is in the list
else
{
   index = ~index;
   if(index == sorted.Length)
      found = sorted[index - 1];
   if(index == 0)
      found = sorted[0];
   else
   {
      var val1 = sorted[index];
      var val2 = sorted[index - 1];
      found = Math.Abs((val1 - date).Ticks) < Math.Abs((val2 - date).Ticks) ? val1 : val2;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this, one simple approach is to traverse through a sorted list until you find a match.

First, you need a list that is sorted. You can sort a list by using something similar to this:

```
static List<DateTime> SortAscending(List<DateTime> list)
{
    list.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
    return list;
}
```

And then traverse through the list until you find an exact match. Here's a **rough snippet**:

```
foreach(DateTime dt in list)
{
    if(myDate>dt)
        continue;
    else
        //You've got the answer here
}
```

You also have to handle exceptions where all dates are larger or smaller than given.

Answer (score 0):

Go through all dates and find the difference. Remember the one with a smaller difference and go to the next date in the list.

If the list is small you can use sorting and all benefits of LINQ as in example by @John.

```
private static DateTime FineNearestDateTime(IEnumerable<DateTime> dates, DateTime dateTime)
{
    var difference = double.MaxValue;
    var nearestDate = DateTime.MinValue;
    foreach (var item in dates)
    {
        if (item == dateTime)
            return dateTime;
        var newDiff = Math.Abs((dateTime - item).TotalMilliseconds);
        if (newDiff < difference)
        {
            nearestDate = dateTime;
            difference = newDiff;
        }
    }

    return nearestDate;
}
```

Comment: var difference = double.MaxValue;
var nearestDate = DateTime.MinValue;                                                                                      Whats the value in difference and nearestdate? is it something like default values?

Comment: @Swathi both are self-explanatory. We need to set max value in order to find the smallest (find a date with less difference), and minValue was set as some value in case list is empty.